# Android SQL INSERT Date into Access

Tags: android, sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I have an Android application that sends data to an ASP page, which then sends the information to an Access database. This worked fully before. Recently we had an issue with our server and now that it has been reset the date field does not submit properly. I have very limited experience and am wondering if this is an issue with my SQL syntax. I will post all relevant code just in case it is something else as well.

Quick breakdown of how my app works. Android code takes date, submits it to an ASP page through the GET method. ASP page uses an SQL statement to insert into an Access database.

Android code (GET Statement):

```
String vars = "&ReportDate=" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                    + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))
```

ASP code (SQL Statement):

```
mySQLR=mySQLR & vReportDate & ", "
```

Is my SQL syntax incorrect for submission into an Access database?

**EDIT**

**My Issue** is the date field is not being written to the database when every other field is. The date field has now been left bank in every field.

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting? Also include the full sql statement please.

Comment: My apologies. I'm not getting an error, it just isn't inserting the date. I have approximately 25 other fields that all are saved to the database, but the date field remains blank.

Comment: if I remember correctly you need to use a '#' sign as date delimiter for dates in MS Access!

Comment: That did help. I figured out the issue though. The "ReportDate" field was the first field being appended to the the URL and having the "&" in front of it was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable "ReportDate" is the first field being appended to the url for submission through the GET method and the "&" is unnecessary and causing that particular field to not be submitted.

**Editted code:**

```
String vars = "ReportDate=" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" + String.valueOf
```